# Login Automation Using Selenium Not Working Properly

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have built a login Automator using Selenium, and the code executes without errors but the script doesn't login. The page is stuck at login page, email and password are entered, but login is not completed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOH0V.jpg)

I have tried 2 ways to login:

1. By clicking on Login through Click ()

```
e = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Login']")
e.click()
```

2. Using Enter in password area

```
password_element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

But neither of them logs me in, even though I can see the button being clicked, and name and password being entered.
I also tried adding a wait time, but the problem is not solved. What an I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class QuoraScraper:

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = ''
        self.dataframe = ''
        self.credentials = {
            'email': 'email',
            'password': 'password'
        }
        self.questions = []
        self.answers = []


    def start_driver(self):
        options = Options()
        options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

    def close_driver(self):
        self.driver.close()

    def open_url(self, url):
        self.driver.get(url)

    def initialize_columns(self, columns):
        self.dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

    def set_credentials(self, email, password):
        self.credentials['email'] = email
        self.credentials['password'] = password

    def login(self):
        self.open_url('https://www.quora.com/')

        if (self.credentials['email'] and self.credentials['password']):

            email_element = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, 'email')
            password_element = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, 'password')
            email_element.send_keys(self.credentials['email'])
            password_element.send_keys(self.credentials['password'])
            # I tried adding a wait time but the script is not successful either way
            #self.driver.maximize_window()  # For maximizing window
            #self.driver.implicitly_wait(20)  # gives an implicit wait for 20 seconds
            # I tried clcking on Login through both Click and Enter but neither of them logs me in, even though I can see the button clicking
            password_element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
            e = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Login']")
            e.click()
        else:
            print('Credentials not set. Error')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    scraper = QuoraScraper()
    scraper.start_driver()
    email = "email"
    password = "password"
    scraper.set_credentials(email, password)
    scraper.login()
```

**UPDATE 2:** I get a login popup window after the email and password have been correctly entered and i try to close it by finding the xpath of the X button like this:
[image: POPUP IMAGE]

```
cross = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="close"]')
cross.click()
```

But the element cannot be located:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to
> locate element: //*[@id="close"]

Comment: is  this piece of code what your referring to as the Login button , `e = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Login']")`

Comment: Yes, it finds the Login by  text using xpath @Archiee

Comment: Like i stated below @isabella, the `e` variable does not reference the login button,i tested the code with the xpath i provided and it does click!!

Comment: Ok, i figured out the problem, there is now a pop up window blocking my login attempts. I have written the code to close it, but it cannot be accessed through xpath for some reason. I added the image and code to question, is there any reason the element cannot be accessed now?

Comment: where exactly this pop up window coming from? are you using the `gogole ` to continue the Login or the default form given? have you tried to switch the driver, use `chromedriver` for instance.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typed this `//div[text()='Login']` into source code of quora site to check if this is the correct xpath for the login button, but instead it highlighted the Login text on top of the email, this is the correct `xpath` for the login button :

```
login_btn =  driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/button')
```

Comment: If you sneeze on the html that path will break.  Write relative XPaths such as //button[.//*[text()='Login']]

Comment: Appreciate the answer, now i get a new error by using this, added it in the question

Comment: Hay @Isabella, sorry for the late feedback, i looked into the update you provided, like @Rakesh said in his answer, is the `Login` button appears to be activated when the password gets filled in?? and/or did you get the option to check the `captcha`?  try to incorporate `time.sleep()` after the password fill in,!!

Comment: You can test The relative xpath @DominicGiallombardo provided as well!!! .

Answer (score 1):

Before you start with scripting. please understand the AUT. how exactly it works.
using quora login page. as you enter the valid email address there is backend validation happening with server if the email is valid.

Unless and untill email address is validated and correct password the login button is disabled.
Add an intermediate layer where check the attribute or wait for the attribute disabled=false. then proceed with click. this should solve the issue.